# redux immutable state change when adding item to array

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this code sample, based on something very similar I saw in a book about React. It basically illustrates what happens in a reducer when a new item is added to a todo list:

```
let todos = [
{
  text: 'first',
  done: false
},
{
  text: 'second',
  done: false
}  
]

let state = { todos };

let firstTodosRef = todos[0];

let output = {};

Object.assign(output, state, {
    todos: [
       ...state.todos,
      {
        text: 'third',
        done: false
      }
    ]
})

console.log(output.todos[0] === firstTodosRef)
```

The console.log in the last line outputs true, since Object.assign doesn't do a deep copy. My question is, does this make the code invalid from the perspective of Redux and immutability, or is it still ok because we are only concerned with the addition of a new item?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Proper immutable updates should make copies of all the objects and arrays that are actually being updated and modify those, but use the original references for all other existing values.  So yes, that code appears to be correct.

For more examples, see the [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) page in the Redux docs.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid code form the perspective of 'immutability'. Because you added a new todo your created a new state object instead of mutating it, but because you kept the first two items, when testing for equality between the new version and the old you get `true` as a result.

The whole is different, but some parts are still the same. The fact that some pieces remain identical can be used to assert that despite the fact that state changed, you can still keep parts of the old view and only update what is different.